# unzip to a specific folder

Tags: zip

I want to unzip the contents of a zipfile called `mine.zip` into `/yours/` but when I do it using the `-d` flag it keeps going into `/yours/crap/` etc which is not I want

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can flatted the entire contents of the zip file using `cd /yours && unzip -j /path/to/mine.zip`. The `-j` option is called "junk paths" and just dumps each file into the current directory instead of extracting any directory structure.

To be more exactly than that, i.e. extracting directory structures except for the top one, you will need to know the name of the folder inside the zip that you want to skip creating and specifically ask `unzip` to extract the contents of that folder.

Unfortunately `unzip` is not a flexable as `tar` with it's various strip folder path options that it can handle for gzip, bzip2, lzip and other compression formats.

Comment: I'm aware of that option, but its not what I'm looking for though. I need the folder structure to stay intact  ... I just need the 'parent folder' name changed

Comment: I just looked into using p7zip's `7z` that also handles normal zips nicely, but it has the same to extract options, flatted everything or keep everything. I think you are going to have to script this yourself. `unzip mine.zip; mv stuff/* ./; rmdir stuff`